# Schedule Optimization Question - Variant of Job Shop

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, job-scheduling

I am looking to build code on python for a variant of the job shop problem.

The differences are:

The goal is to combine as many tasks to the fewest number of machines without overlap while ensure the most efficient outcome

The machines have a capacity to run all day and will be measured in minutes 0-1440 minutes

there are multiple jobs, there is no order to the jobs, but each job has its own defined schedule

e.g. job 1: starts at 02:00 (140 minutes) and ends at 08:00 (480 minutes)

e.g. job 2: starts at 07:00 (420 minutes) and ends at 19:00 (1140 minutes)

e.g. job 3: starts at 08:00 (480 minutes) and ends at 20:00 (1200 minutes)

e.g. job 4: starts at 02:00 (140 minutes) and ends at 05:00 (300 minutes)

Can you help with the ideation / or code variation of the job shop problem to combine the jobs on the fewest number of machines?

Additionally as an extra request if possible (not too complex) would it be possible to incorporate jobs with different schedules during the week?

e.g.

Job 1: runs daily 02:00 - 08:00

job 2: runs Monday and Thursday only 07:00 - 19:00 etc.

In essence - assume I have a weekly Gannt chart / schedule with 50 machines - each with a single job, i want to compress the Gantt chart to reduce number of machines if they have space to run more than one job (simple illustration going from A to the more efficient B)

Have tried the job shop problem, and researching other problems but couldn't find a similar problem statement

[image: Gantt chart]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think this is better solved with combinatorial optimization, which in Python Google's OR-Tools has relatively nice bindings and good performance

Comment: `job 1: starts at 02:00 (140 minutes)` What does "140 minutes" mean in this context?

Comment: If the job times (start and duration) are fixed in advance, then this is not a scheduling problem, so searching on that will lead you to much that is interesting but irrelevant to your case. It sounds like you are looking at a resource allocation problem, finding which machine should do each job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a super difficult problem to solve.

Instead of talking about jobs (which may repeat during the week), it may be easier to talk about individual **sub-jobs**. The first thing to do is to find out if two sub-jobs k and k' overlap. If this is the case, they cannot run on the same machine. The data structure to hold the overlap information can be calculated in advance (before the model runs).

The best thing is to first write down on a piece of paper the mathematical model of the problem. I propose something like:

[image]

The objective is to minimize the number of machines we use (i.e. to which we assign sub-jobs to). The first constraint says: assign each sub-job to exactly one machine. The second constraint: if sub-jobs k and k' overlap, they can't run on the same machine. The third constraint: if a machine is not used, we can't assign any sub-jobs to it. The whole model is expressed in terms of individual sub-jobs instead of  (job,day) combinations.

This model can be implemented using any reasonable MIP solver. It is not very difficult to implement (it is rather simple: most of the work is to get the data in shape and calculate the overlap data) and not very difficult to solve (at least for the data set I used). The mathematical model above is sufficiently detailed and precise that you are advised to follow it as closely as possible.

I tried it out with the following random data:

```
----     24 PARAMETER start  start time

job1   206.000,    job2  1012.000,    job3   661.000,    job4   361.000,    job5   350.000,    job6   269.000,    job7   420.000
job8  1028.000,    job9    80.000,    job10  600.000,    job11 1198.000,    job12  695.000,    job13 1190.000,    job14  915.000
job15  156.000,    job16  768.000,    job17  191.000,    job18  300.000,    job19  803.000,    job20  522.000,    job21  432.000
job22  422.000,    job23  157.000,    job24  180.000,    job25  707.000,    job26  997.000,    job27  277.000,    job28  799.000
job29  931.000,    job30  364.000,    job31  132.000,    job32  603.000,    job33  192.000,    job34 1047.000,    job35  318.000
job36  343.000,    job37  713.000,    job38  867.000,    job39  754.000,    job40  557.000,    job41  496.000,    job42  141.000
job43  377.000,    job44   55.000,    job45  406.000,    job46  218.000,    job47  775.000,    job48  673.000,    job49  924.000
job50  357.000


----     24 PARAMETER end  finish time

job1   841.663,    job2  1721.541,    job3  1270.409,    job4   702.414,    job5   537.411,    job6   468.961,    job7  1040.176
job8  1573.341,    job9   224.589,    job10 1338.041,    job11 1374.758,    job12  952.016,    job13 1719.993,    job14 1620.162
job15  414.936,    job16  914.630,    job17  767.402,    job18  904.559,    job19 1226.702,    job20  921.797,    job21  741.567
job22  734.209,    job23  378.792,    job24 1028.091,    job25 1123.352,    job26 1728.052,    job27  631.027,    job28 1016.877
job29 1635.122,    job30  538.001,    job31  409.572,    job32  726.951,    job33  522.298,    job34 1556.884,    job35  556.003
job36  598.852,    job37 1090.897,    job38 1234.187,    job39 1125.228,    job40 1428.902,    job41 1391.010,    job42  549.524
job43  787.853,    job44  777.143,    job45  835.414,    job46 1050.215,    job47  988.271,    job48 1366.674,    job49 1087.226
job50  926.514


----     24 PARAMETER length  length of job (minutes)

job1  635.663,    job2  709.541,    job3  609.409,    job4  341.414,    job5  187.411,    job6  199.961,    job7  620.176
job8  545.341,    job9  144.589,    job10 738.041,    job11 176.758,    job12 257.016,    job13 529.993,    job14 705.162
job15 258.936,    job16 146.630,    job17 576.402,    job18 604.559,    job19 423.702,    job20 399.797,    job21 309.567
job22 312.209,    job23 221.792,    job24 848.091,    job25 416.352,    job26 731.052,    job27 354.027,    job28 217.877
job29 704.122,    job30 174.001,    job31 277.572,    job32 123.951,    job33 330.298,    job34 509.884,    job35 238.003
job36 255.852,    job37 377.897,    job38 367.187,    job39 371.228,    job40 871.902,    job41 895.010,    job42 408.524
job43 410.853,    job44 722.143,    job45 429.414,    job46 832.215,    job47 213.271,    job48 693.674,    job49 163.226
job50 569.514


----     24 SET jd  jobs need to run on certain days

             day1        day2        day3        day4        day5        day6        day7

job1          YES         YES                                             YES
job2                      YES                                 YES
job3                                  YES                     YES                     YES
job4                                  YES         YES                                 YES
job6                      YES                                 YES                     YES
job7                                              YES                     YES         YES
job8                                  YES         YES                     YES
job9                      YES
job10         YES         YES         YES                     YES                     YES
job11                                                         YES
job12                     YES         YES         YES         YES         YES         YES
job13                                 YES         YES
job14                                 YES
job15                                                         YES
job16                                             YES                                 YES
job17                                                         YES
job18                     YES
job19         YES                                                                     YES
job21                                 YES                     YES                     YES
job22         YES                                                         YES
job23                                             YES                     YES
job24                                 YES                                 YES
job25                                 YES
job26                                 YES                     YES
job27         YES                                             YES
job28         YES                                             YES
job30         YES                                             YES
job31                                 YES
job32                     YES                                 YES
job33         YES                                                         YES         YES
job34         YES                                                         YES         YES
job35                     YES                                             YES
job36                     YES                                                         YES
job37         YES                                             YES
job38         YES                     YES                     YES
job39                                             YES         YES
job40                     YES                                                         YES
job42         YES                                 YES                     YES
job44         YES
job45                                                         YES
job46                     YES
job48                                             YES         YES
job49                                                         YES                     YES


----     29 PARAMETER counts  

jobs    43.000,    subjobs 93.000


----     49 SET k  subjobs

subjob1 ,    subjob2 ,    subjob3 ,    subjob4 ,    subjob5 ,    subjob6 ,    subjob7 ,    subjob8 ,    subjob9 ,    subjob10
subjob11,    subjob12,    subjob13,    subjob14,    subjob15,    subjob16,    subjob17,    subjob18,    subjob19,    subjob20
subjob21,    subjob22,    subjob23,    subjob24,    subjob25,    subjob26,    subjob27,    subjob28,    subjob29,    subjob30
subjob31,    subjob32,    subjob33,    subjob34,    subjob35,    subjob36,    subjob37,    subjob38,    subjob39,    subjob40
subjob41,    subjob42,    subjob43,    subjob44,    subjob45,    subjob46,    subjob47,    subjob48,    subjob49,    subjob50
subjob51,    subjob52,    subjob53,    subjob54,    subjob55,    subjob56,    subjob57,    subjob58,    subjob59,    subjob60
subjob61,    subjob62,    subjob63,    subjob64,    subjob65,    subjob66,    subjob67,    subjob68,    subjob69,    subjob70
subjob71,    subjob72,    subjob73,    subjob74,    subjob75,    subjob76,    subjob77,    subjob78,    subjob79,    subjob80
subjob81,    subjob82,    subjob83,    subjob84,    subjob85,    subjob86,    subjob87,    subjob88,    subjob89,    subjob90
subjob91,    subjob92,    subjob93


----     49 SET map  mapping between jobs/days and subjobs

job1 .day1.subjob1 ,    job1 .day2.subjob2 ,    job1 .day6.subjob3 ,    job2 .day2.subjob4 ,    job2 .day5.subjob5 
job3 .day3.subjob6 ,    job3 .day5.subjob7 ,    job3 .day7.subjob8 ,    job4 .day3.subjob9 ,    job4 .day4.subjob10
job4 .day7.subjob11,    job6 .day2.subjob12,    job6 .day5.subjob13,    job6 .day7.subjob14,    job7 .day4.subjob15
job7 .day6.subjob16,    job7 .day7.subjob17,    job8 .day3.subjob18,    job8 .day4.subjob19,    job8 .day6.subjob20
job9 .day2.subjob21,    job10.day1.subjob22,    job10.day2.subjob23,    job10.day3.subjob24,    job10.day5.subjob25
job10.day7.subjob26,    job11.day5.subjob27,    job12.day2.subjob28,    job12.day3.subjob29,    job12.day4.subjob30
job12.day5.subjob31,    job12.day6.subjob32,    job12.day7.subjob33,    job13.day3.subjob34,    job13.day4.subjob35
job14.day3.subjob36,    job15.day5.subjob37,    job16.day4.subjob38,    job16.day7.subjob39,    job17.day5.subjob40
job18.day2.subjob41,    job19.day1.subjob42,    job19.day7.subjob43,    job21.day3.subjob44,    job21.day5.subjob45
job21.day7.subjob46,    job22.day1.subjob47,    job22.day6.subjob48,    job23.day4.subjob49,    job23.day6.subjob50
job24.day3.subjob51,    job24.day6.subjob52,    job25.day3.subjob53,    job26.day3.subjob54,    job26.day5.subjob55
job27.day1.subjob56,    job27.day5.subjob57,    job28.day1.subjob58,    job28.day5.subjob59,    job30.day1.subjob60
job30.day5.subjob61,    job31.day3.subjob62,    job32.day2.subjob63,    job32.day5.subjob64,    job33.day1.subjob65
job33.day6.subjob66,    job33.day7.subjob67,    job34.day1.subjob68,    job34.day6.subjob69,    job34.day7.subjob70
job35.day2.subjob71,    job35.day6.subjob72,    job36.day2.subjob73,    job36.day7.subjob74,    job37.day1.subjob75
job37.day5.subjob76,    job38.day1.subjob77,    job38.day3.subjob78,    job38.day5.subjob79,    job39.day4.subjob80
job39.day5.subjob81,    job40.day2.subjob82,    job40.day7.subjob83,    job42.day1.subjob84,    job42.day4.subjob85
job42.day6.subjob86,    job44.day1.subjob87,    job45.day5.subjob88,    job46.day2.subjob89,    job48.day4.subjob90
job48.day5.subjob91,    job49.day5.subjob92,    job49.day7.subjob93


----     64 PARAMETER start2  start time of subjob

subjob1   206.000,    subjob2  1646.000,    subjob3  7406.000,    subjob4  2452.000,    subjob5  6772.000,    subjob6  3541.000
subjob7  6421.000,    subjob8  9301.000,    subjob9  3241.000,    subjob10 4681.000,    subjob11 9001.000,    subjob12 1709.000
subjob13 6029.000,    subjob14 8909.000,    subjob15 4740.000,    subjob16 7620.000,    subjob17 9060.000,    subjob18 3908.000
subjob19 5348.000,    subjob20 8228.000,    subjob21 1520.000,    subjob22  600.000,    subjob23 2040.000,    subjob24 3480.000
subjob25 6360.000,    subjob26 9240.000,    subjob27 6958.000,    subjob28 2135.000,    subjob29 3575.000,    subjob30 5015.000
subjob31 6455.000,    subjob32 7895.000,    subjob33 9335.000,    subjob34 4070.000,    subjob35 5510.000,    subjob36 3795.000
subjob37 5916.000,    subjob38 5088.000,    subjob39 9408.000,    subjob40 5951.000,    subjob41 1740.000,    subjob42  803.000
subjob43 9443.000,    subjob44 3312.000,    subjob45 6192.000,    subjob46 9072.000,    subjob47  422.000,    subjob48 7622.000
subjob49 4477.000,    subjob50 7357.000,    subjob51 3060.000,    subjob52 7380.000,    subjob53 3587.000,    subjob54 3877.000
subjob55 6757.000,    subjob56  277.000,    subjob57 6037.000,    subjob58  799.000,    subjob59 6559.000,    subjob60  364.000
subjob61 6124.000,    subjob62 3012.000,    subjob63 2043.000,    subjob64 6363.000,    subjob65  192.000,    subjob66 7392.000
subjob67 8832.000,    subjob68 1047.000,    subjob69 8247.000,    subjob70 9687.000,    subjob71 1758.000,    subjob72 7518.000
subjob73 1783.000,    subjob74 8983.000,    subjob75  713.000,    subjob76 6473.000,    subjob77  867.000,    subjob78 3747.000
subjob79 6627.000,    subjob80 5074.000,    subjob81 6514.000,    subjob82 1997.000,    subjob83 9197.000,    subjob84  141.000
subjob85 4461.000,    subjob86 7341.000,    subjob87   55.000,    subjob88 6166.000,    subjob89 1658.000,    subjob90 4993.000
subjob91 6433.000,    subjob92 6684.000,    subjob93 9564.000


----     64 PARAMETER end2  end time of subjob

subjob1    841.663,    subjob2   2281.663,    subjob3   8041.663,    subjob4   3161.541,    subjob5   7481.541
subjob6   4150.409,    subjob7   7030.409,    subjob8   9910.409,    subjob9   3582.414,    subjob10  5022.414
subjob11  9342.414,    subjob12  1908.961,    subjob13  6228.961,    subjob14  9108.961,    subjob15  5360.176
subjob16  8240.176,    subjob17  9680.176,    subjob18  4453.341,    subjob19  5893.341,    subjob20  8773.341
subjob21  1664.589,    subjob22  1338.041,    subjob23  2778.041,    subjob24  4218.041,    subjob25  7098.041
subjob26  9978.041,    subjob27  7134.758,    subjob28  2392.016,    subjob29  3832.016,    subjob30  5272.016
subjob31  6712.016,    subjob32  8152.016,    subjob33  9592.016,    subjob34  4599.993,    subjob35  6039.993
subjob36  4500.162,    subjob37  6174.936,    subjob38  5234.630,    subjob39  9554.630,    subjob40  6527.402
subjob41  2344.559,    subjob42  1226.702,    subjob43  9866.702,    subjob44  3621.567,    subjob45  6501.567
subjob46  9381.567,    subjob47   734.209,    subjob48  7934.209,    subjob49  4698.792,    subjob50  7578.792
subjob51  3908.091,    subjob52  8228.091,    subjob53  4003.352,    subjob54  4608.052,    subjob55  7488.052
subjob56   631.027,    subjob57  6391.027,    subjob58  1016.877,    subjob59  6776.877,    subjob60   538.001
subjob61  6298.001,    subjob62  3289.572,    subjob63  2166.951,    subjob64  6486.951,    subjob65   522.298
subjob66  7722.298,    subjob67  9162.298,    subjob68  1556.884,    subjob69  8756.884,    subjob70 10196.884
subjob71  1996.003,    subjob72  7756.003,    subjob73  2038.852,    subjob74  9238.852,    subjob75  1090.897
subjob76  6850.897,    subjob77  1234.187,    subjob78  4114.187,    subjob79  6994.187,    subjob80  5445.228
subjob81  6885.228,    subjob82  2868.902,    subjob83 10068.902,    subjob84   549.524,    subjob85  4869.524
subjob86  7749.524,    subjob87   777.143,    subjob88  6595.414,    subjob89  2490.215,    subjob90  5686.674
subjob91  7126.674,    subjob92  6847.226,    subjob93  9727.226
```

Some jobs, due to my random data, don't appear in any of the days. So we don't have 50 jobs here, but just 43. The number of subjobs is 93.

This model solves very fast: 0.06 seconds. Here is the solution:

```
----    106 VARIABLE x.L  assign job to machine

            machine1    machine2    machine3    machine4    machine5    machine6    machine7    machine8    machine9   machine10

subjob1        1.000
subjob2        1.000
subjob3        1.000
subjob4        1.000
subjob5                    1.000
subjob6        1.000
subjob7        1.000
subjob8        1.000
subjob9                    1.000
subjob10       1.000
subjob11                   1.000
subjob12                   1.000
subjob13       1.000
subjob14       1.000
subjob15                   1.000
subjob16                   1.000
subjob17                               1.000
subjob18                   1.000
subjob19       1.000
subjob20       1.000
subjob21                   1.000
subjob22                   1.000
subjob23                   1.000
subjob24                               1.000
subjob25                               1.000
subjob26                                           1.000
subjob27                                           1.000
subjob28                               1.000
subjob29                                           1.000
subjob30                               1.000
subjob31                   1.000
subjob32                               1.000
subjob33                                                       1.000
subjob34                                           1.000
subjob35                   1.000
subjob36                                                       1.000
subjob37                               1.000
subjob38       1.000
subjob39                   1.000
subjob40                                           1.000
subjob41                                           1.000
subjob42                               1.000
subjob43                                                                   1.000
subjob44                                                       1.000
subjob45                                                       1.000
subjob46                                                                   1.000
subjob47                               1.000
subjob48                                           1.000
subjob49                   1.000
subjob50                               1.000
subjob51                                                                   1.000
subjob52                                                       1.000
subjob53                                                                               1.000
subjob54                                                                                           1.000
subjob55                                                                   1.000
subjob56                                           1.000
subjob57                                                                   1.000
subjob58                                           1.000
subjob59                                           1.000
subjob60                   1.000
subjob61                   1.000
subjob62                               1.000
subjob63                                                       1.000
subjob64                                                                               1.000
subjob65                                                       1.000
subjob66                                                                               1.000
subjob67                                           1.000
subjob68       1.000
subjob69                   1.000
subjob70                   1.000
subjob71                               1.000
subjob72                                                                   1.000
subjob73                                                       1.000
subjob74                                                       1.000
subjob75                                                       1.000
subjob76                                                                                           1.000
subjob77                                                                   1.000
subjob78                                                                                                       1.000
subjob79                                                       1.000
subjob80                                           1.000
subjob81                                                                               1.000
subjob82                                                                   1.000
subjob83                                                                               1.000
subjob84                                                                   1.000
subjob85                               1.000
subjob86                                                                                           1.000
subjob87                                                                               1.000
subjob88                                                                                                       1.000
subjob89                                                                               1.000
subjob90                                                       1.000
subjob91                                                                                                                   1.000
subjob92                                                                                                       1.000
subjob93                                                                                           1.000


----    106 VARIABLE used.L  

machine1  1.000,    machine2  1.000,    machine3  1.000,    machine4  1.000,    machine5  1.000,    machine6  1.000
machine7  1.000,    machine8  1.000,    machine9  1.000,    machine10 1.000


----    106 VARIABLE num.L                 =       10.000  number of machines needed

----    110 PARAMETER assignments  

              machine1    machine2    machine3    machine4    machine5    machine6    machine7    machine8    machine9   machine10

job1 .day1       1.000
job1 .day2       1.000
job1 .day6       1.000
job2 .day2       1.000
job2 .day5                   1.000
job3 .day3       1.000
job3 .day5       1.000
job3 .day7       1.000
job4 .day3                   1.000
job4 .day4       1.000
job4 .day7                   1.000
job6 .day2                   1.000
job6 .day5       1.000
job6 .day7       1.000
job7 .day4                   1.000
job7 .day6                   1.000
job7 .day7                               1.000
job8 .day3                   1.000
job8 .day4       1.000
job8 .day6       1.000
job9 .day2                   1.000
job10.day1                   1.000
job10.day2                   1.000
job10.day3                               1.000
job10.day5                               1.000
job10.day7                                           1.000
job11.day5                                           1.000
job12.day2                               1.000
job12.day3                                           1.000
job12.day4                               1.000
job12.day5                   1.000
job12.day6                               1.000
job12.day7                                                       1.000
job13.day3                                           1.000
job13.day4                   1.000
job14.day3                                                       1.000
job15.day5                               1.000
job16.day4       1.000
job16.day7                   1.000
job17.day5                                           1.000
job18.day2                                           1.000
job19.day1                               1.000
job19.day7                                                                   1.000
job21.day3                                                       1.000
job21.day5                                                       1.000
job21.day7                                                                   1.000
job22.day1                               1.000
job22.day6                                           1.000
job23.day4                   1.000
job23.day6                               1.000
job24.day3                                                                   1.000
job24.day6                                                       1.000
job25.day3                                                                               1.000
job26.day3                                                                                           1.000
job26.day5                                                                   1.000
job27.day1                                           1.000
job27.day5                                                                   1.000
job28.day1                                           1.000
job28.day5                                           1.000
job30.day1                   1.000
job30.day5                   1.000
job31.day3                               1.000
job32.day2                                                       1.000
job32.day5                                                                               1.000
job33.day1                                                       1.000
job33.day6                                                                               1.000
job33.day7                                           1.000
job34.day1       1.000
job34.day6                   1.000
job34.day7                   1.000
job35.day2                               1.000
job35.day6                                                                   1.000
job36.day2                                                       1.000
job36.day7                                                       1.000
job37.day1                                                       1.000
job37.day5                                                                                           1.000
job38.day1                                                                   1.000
job38.day3                                                                                                       1.000
job38.day5                                                       1.000
job39.day4                                           1.000
job39.day5                                                                               1.000
job40.day2                                                                   1.000
job40.day7                                                                               1.000
job42.day1                                                                   1.000
job42.day4                               1.000
job42.day6                                                                                           1.000
job44.day1                                                                               1.000
job45.day5                                                                                                       1.000
job46.day2                                                                               1.000
job48.day4                                                       1.000
job48.day5                                                                                                                   1.000
job49.day5                                                                                                       1.000
job49.day7                                                                                           1.000
```

We need 10 machines for the assignments to be non-overlapping. The number of sub-jobs for some of the machines is very small. Machine 10 has only one sub-job. The results look fine at first sight:

[image]

The numbers are the job numbers. E.g. job 1 appears in day 1, 2 and 6 all on machine 1.

Comment: Thank you this was awesome work and demonstration Erwin! I do have to say it may be very simple to someone with your experience, but I wanted to know if there is a popular MIP code / library / example I can use to implement your constraints and run the optimization?

Comment: There are many tools and solvers, varying from to open source to commercial. Some commercial solvers are free for academics.

Comment: If you can accept good instead of optimal solutions, you may want to use a heuristic. This problem can be stated as a Graph Coloring problem. There are easy to use graph packages. See http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2023/02/assigning-jobs-to-machines-without.html for details. (Note: that write-up uses a slightly different definition of overlap so the results are not exactly the same as above).